# Overriding jquery .load() function - handle callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding

I have overloaded the .load() funciton of jQuery to meet my CrossDomain requirements.

```
(function ($) { 
    var _load = $.fn.load; 
    $.fn.load = function(url, params, callback) { 
        if (url.match('^http')) { 
            $(this).load("read_page.php?p="+url);
            return this;
        }
        else{
            return _load.apply(this, arguments); 
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The "read_page.php" calls PHP curl to get page from crossdomain.

The part of code calling the above overrided function is:

```
$(trg).load(user_folder+shw+qs, function(){
                        showErr("Updation Successfull", trg);
                        $(".divErr").css("border-color","#4F8A10");
                        $(".divErr").css("background","url(images/img_suc.png) no-repeat 10px 50%, left;");
                        $(".divErr").css("background-color","#DFF2BF");
                    }).html(vLoading);
```

The **.html(vLoading)** part is doing fine as my code returns value of **this**.

The **function(){...}** part is not working as my code has no part to handle **callback**

Need help to handle **callback** in my custom override function.

Comment: Try this `if (callback != undefined) callback();` after this line `$(this).load("read_page.php?p="+url);`

Answer (score 0):

try this version:

```
(function ($) { 
    var _load = $.fn.load; 
    $.fn.load = function(url, params, callback) { 
        if ( url.match('^http') ) {
            var params = params || {},
                callback = callback || function () {};
            _load.call(this, "read_page.php?p="+url, params, callback );
            return this;
        }
        else {
            return _load.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. On which selector this load will work? need to place **$(this) or this** some where in the code _load("read_page.php?p...

Comment: you're right. i've edited the post and added a 'call'-statement to the _load-function.